# How can I do a FULL JOIN of MULTIPLE TABLES in MySQL

Tags: mysql

we have been searching for it but all we see is 2 tables by the left and right inner/outer joins.

I love you guys.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN.

As you mention, you can simulate a FULL OUTER JOIN of two tables using a combination of LEFT and RIGHT OUTER joins.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.b_id = tableB.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tableA RIGHT JOIN tableB ON tableA.b_id = tableB.id
WHERE tableA.b_id IS NULL
```

The same technique can in theory be extended to more than two tables. I'd suggest first using the above approach to join two of the tables as a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html). Then use the same approach again to join the view to the third table.

Comment: sorry to bother you again because I am just starting to learn about MySQL, but how can I possibly join the view table in the third table.

Comment: @jan estepa: You join to a view in the same way as you would join to a table: with the JOIN keyword.

Comment: well it will not necessary get messy, but it will get slow. The whole above query can be a VIEW, and with tableA -> viewA, tableB -> viewC you get a clean solution which would probably be slow (as the VIEW results ?will need? to be materialized before join); alternatively splitting to the six base combinations you would be able to write UNION ALL that should be using index scans (but now probably justified to be called messy).

Comment: @jan estepa: It's probably best to avoid the need in the first place. Find a way to change your query so that one of the FULL OUTER joins can be written as a LEFT OUTER instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to say about the love part, but

Having tables named a and b:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a, b
```

Does this the trick?

Comment: This is CROSS JOIN, FULL refers to FULL OUTER.